# How to subscribe to application shutdown event in class library

Tags: c#, events, class-library, subscription, application-shutdown

There is a class library used by some application. It contains a class A for external usage with a static field of another private class B inside the library. User application uses instances of class A from the library.

As the application shutdowns I'd like to perform some clean up in class B.
Is it possible to catch application shutdown event in class B without any action from user application?

```
class B
{
    public B()
    {
        // attach Handler() to applicaiton shutdown event
    }

    void Handler()
    {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        Application.ApplicationExit += new EventHandler(Application_ApplicationExit);
    }

    void Application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do cleanup of your class
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand this correctly, your model looks like this:

[image: Initial scenario]

You would then like to have `ClassB` communicate with `Application` through `ClassA` like shown below:

[image: Goal]

From an object-oriented design standpoint, this violates the [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which states that **objects should only talk to their direct neighbors**. In this regard I would suggest you to do the cleanup in `ClassA`, if possible.

From an implementation point of view, I would let `ClassA` **explicitly state its dependency** on `Application` by taking an instance of it in the constructor. This way you could easily subscribe to any events published by `Application` inside `ClassA` or, potentially, `ClassB` since [inner classes in C# can access the outer class' private members](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/01/685248.aspx):

```
public class A
{
    private readonly Application application;

    public A(Application application)
    {
        if (application == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("application");
        }

        this.application = application;
        this.application.ApplicationExit += application_ApplicationExit;
    }

    private void application_ApplicationExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Perform cleanup
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the interaction path is app->A->B
There are no backward paths, class B runs on its own and fetches some data from db in a thread and synch it with its mem.
Class A query B for the db kept in its mem

Comment: App have interface object of A implementation, which is repository with only one function to FindAll(), and I needed app shutdown event in B to synchronize mem with db

Comment: @Chesnokov Yuriy Subscribing to an event published by another class creates a strong association between the subscriber and the publisher. In this sense, if `ClassB` subscribes to an event published by `Application` then objects of `ClassB` have a strong dependency on the `Application` object. I still think that this kind of associations should be *made explicit in the design* to raise awareness of any possible side effects that could result from changes.

Comment: I see, then destructor ~B() is the right place to catch it, since B is declared as static field in A and will be called only once. 
I tried that but as destructor is called the logger disposed of its observers and log message is not saved. I need to debug the issue further

Comment: ~B() is called after program flow return from Program.Main() where all logging is finalized and it is not possible to save results of ~B() to log